# Getting "FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just made delete chatting room. It works well when I login with my ID. But when I login with someone else's ID, I get this error.

> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

What should I do? This is my code:

```
const ChatRoomList = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const userChatRef = db
    .collection('chats')
    .where('users', 'array-contains', user.email);
  const [chatsSnapshot] = useCollection(userChatRef);
  return (
    <Container>
      {chatsSnapshot?.docs.map(chat => (
        <ChatList key={chat.id} id={chat.id} users={chat.data().users} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

[image: when I login with gmail ID it worked but when I login bb@naver.com < this ID I get the error]

when I login with gmail ID it worked but when I login bb@naver.com < this ID I get the error

[image: no problem data]

no problem data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty explicit. If it indeed from the code you shared, it seems that `user.email` is `undefined` in:

```
.where('users', 'array-contains', user.email);
```

It's impossible for us to say why this value is undefined, but you can prevent getting an error by checking for a value before executing the query:

```
const ChatRoomList = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  if (!user || !user.email) return; //  Add this line
  const userChatRef = db
    .collection('chats')
    .where('users', 'array-contains', user.email);
  const [chatsSnapshot] = useCollection(userChatRef);
  return (
    <Container>
      {chatsSnapshot?.docs.map(chat => (
        <ChatList key={chat.id} id={chat.id} users={chat.data().users} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but it didn't work. still same issue

Comment: If the change came from the line indicated, it seems quite unlikely that you'll get the exact same error after making this change.

Comment: you cannot return early from an hook function before the useCollection hook is called. this would change the order of hook calls and breaks the rules of hooks